# access multiple key from azure key vault as data source

Tags: azure, terraform, devops, azure-keyvault

Is it possible to access multiple keys as data source in other resources? I mean I am deploying kafka and accessing multiple key from azure key vault but the mentioned code is not working.

````
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "userlist" 
{ name = "acctestusrgw" 
values = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id}" 
name = "acctestusrvm" 
values = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id}" }```
````

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to access multiple keys from azure key vault via using [data source: azurerm_key_vault_secret](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/key_vault_secret.html).

You should use the data source block for each key or secret separately. Then you could reference from the output in other resources.

For example,

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "existing" {
  name                = "mykeyvault"
  resource_group_name = "myrg"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "userlist1" {
  name = "secret1" 
  key_vault_id = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id}" 
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "userlist2"{
  name = "secret2" 
  key_vault_id = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id}" 
}


output "secret_value1" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.userlist1.value}"
}

output "secret_value2" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.userlist2.value}"
}
```

output,

[image]